# How do I get a song to repeat in the Music App in IOS8.4.1?

Tags: music, ios

I can find the repeat button in the Music App for IOS8.4.1, when clicked or highlighted the song does not repeat.  The shuffle button does work.
How do I make this button work?
Is there a work-around that will allow me to repeat a song or a group of songs?

TIA.

Answer (score 2):

At the bottom of the player, there is a repeat button[image]

Comment: Many thanks! I am now happily repeating.  Seeing your pic of how the activated button should look really helped.  The first click on the button highlighted it, but apparently did not put it into repeat mode.  I had to double click to get the button you show above, which put it into the repeat mode.